# Access public property of object on view

Tags: mvc, concepts

When we are working with some MVC FW on PHP, generally we have a view loading function like `load(string viewName, optional array viewVariables)`. My doubt here is: if we are working with some object, like a table row result, we need pass this object entirely to view or we need pass only what will be need on view?

**Example I: pass object entirely.**

```
$data["text"] = $text_object;

load("text_view", $data);
```

For this case, the view will can access the public property of text object (like title, text and date created). But I need create a getter for property, or I can access it directly? And if the property name has to change?

**Example II: pass only what will be need on view**

```
$data["title"] = $text_object->title;
$data["text"] = $text_object->text;
$data["date_created"] = $text_object->date_created;

load("text_view", $data);
```

In this case, the controller is responsible for sending only what is necessary to view. However, the maintenance becomes a little more complicated, because new information in view also requires a new definition of variable in the controller.

Anyway, I wonder what would be the most acceptable concept for this type of task. Note that I am not talking about coding, and yes, the concept that will be used to develop something similar.